# Connecting the given places using google maps api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, directions, distance-matrix

Let say that a user wants to tour the US. When I list the places I want to travel with the origin and destination, I want the Google API to make a route in the shortest way possible.

For Eg: My Origin: **Las Vegas**, Destination: **New York**. And the places I want to tour are **Texas**, **Utah** and **Ohio**. So I need the Google to connect the shortest distance to visit these places like from **Las Vegas -> Utah -> Texas -> Ohio -> New York**

Is this possible with Google Maps API / Directions API
/ Directions API?

I have searched the documentation, and it has documentation for origin and destination connect not the list of places as mentioned above.

Comment: How many "waypoints" do you want to add? Will you add them in the correct sequence or do you expect the API to place these waypoints in a sequence that makes sense?

Comment: waypoints up to 15 and not in order. I want the waypoints in order.

Comment: I now see that the documentation mentions you are limited to 23 waypoints. In the past, it used to be 8 (if I can remember correctly), so I wonder if this has changed or if this is a typo in the documentation... To be tested. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#waypoint-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Waypoints and the `optimizeWaypoints` option to render a route that includes your waypoints and arranges them *in a more efficient order*.

> By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass `optimizeWaypoints: true` within the `DirectionsRequest` to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Below is a fiddle to help you get started with using waypoints.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/J8aCH/)</kbd>

Comment: Change line 7 to `suppressMarkers: false`. And maybe a quick "thank you" for the help before complaining about something that is not to your liking? This is just a fiddle to help you get started. It's not supposed to be something you can copy/paste in your own code as it is.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that.I was in a hurry get it done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad that it helped!